# AWS Glue job throwing java.lang.OutOfMemoryError while writing to s3

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a glue job that reads from RDS and writes it to s3 in parquet format with partitions.

Below is the script. While the data is loaded into the frame and the count, schema is printed in a log. It fails with an error while writing the parquet to s3.

Also, I have mostly used spark's data frame since I was just testing glue out.

The size of the data is around `150 GB`

```
import json
import sys

from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf, year, month
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_json, struct

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

POSTGRES_USER = "postgres"
POSTGRES_PASSWORD = "postgres"
POSTGRES_JDBC_URL = "<host>"

df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", POSTGRES_JDBC_URL) \
    .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver").option("dbtable", "log") \
    .option("user", POSTGRES_USER).option("password", POSTGRES_PASSWORD).load()


print("Log Count : ", df.count())
print("Log Schema : ", df.printSchema())

df_with_year_and_month = df.withColumn("year", year(col("created_at"))).withColumn("month", month(col("created_at")))

print("Log count : ", df_with_year_and_month.count())
print("Log schema : ", df_with_year_and_month.printSchema())

df_with_year_and_month.write.partitionBy("year", "month").parquet("s3a://datalake-bucket/slogs-parquet",mode="append")
job.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to tell why you got OOM when you don't provide any information about data (i.e. how big is it). However, I can tell that you're reading your Postgres **three times** by counting twice and writing once. So if you have 1TB of data from Postgres, your Spark job would be able to process 3TB of data. That might be the reason. If it still doesn't work, update your question with more insight.

Comment: the data size is 150 GB.

Comment: have you tried to remove the counts? How big is your cluster? what's your worker's spec?